# How to read data from a file and store the names from the file in one vector, and the scores from the file in another?

Tags: c++, file, vector, operators, fstream

My prompt asks:
In this program, we are going to input the name and score of 100 students from a file named
student.txt. This file has been provided to you. You have to use two vector variables, one to store the
student names, and another to store the student scores.

The text file referred to is formatted like:

James 80

Frank 67

Jenny 95

I'm struggling to understand how to read and store two variables from one file into two vectors, so if what I have so far doesn't make sense, I won't be totally shocked.  There is an error message at my >> after infile saying there are no operators that match those operands and I have no idea what to do about that.  Further, I just don't know where to go from here, or how to fix my current code. Any help is appreciated.  Please be patient with me, I'm super new to this.

```
//Name
//This program will read and sort names and grades from a file using functions and vectors
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("student.txt");

    if (infile.fail() == false)
    {
        vector<string> name;
        vector<int> score;

        while (infile >> name)
        {
            infile >> score;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not open the file." << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `infile >> name` to do?

Comment: Also, focus on reading data into *one* vector before trying to read it into two. Simplify your assignment and work with a file with just names. Once you have that much working, you can work on expanding your program to handle scores as well.

Comment: Here is more on simplifying problems, as @JaMit has sensibly proposed: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ Actually I recommend to simplify further, by reading into a string first. Then review how you store a single string into a vector.

Comment: @JaMiT I wrote that by following an older program my professor provided, however, it was under different contexts.  My hope was that it would read the first value and store it under name, and then move to the second under the while loop and store that under score, then repeat. I'm going to try what you said about simplifying the problem

Comment: *You have to use two vector variables, one to store the student names, and another to store the student scores.* Nice to see an assignment that allows using a `vector`, but in the real world you want one `vector` of a structure that aggregates the name and the score. It greatly reduces the amount of book-keeping needed.

Comment: @yellogs Hoping is unlikely to get you very far in programming, it's too exacting for that. If you don't know it's right, it's very unlikely to be right. Of course it mIght not be right even when you 'know' it's right.

Comment: Actually I wonder whether/how it is possible to allow what OP was trying. Shifting from a stream into a vector does make some sense to me. I am aware of overloading operators, but is there anything already available? I am not going to make this a question, but maybe somebody would make an answer here, because I think doing it that way would be an answer here.

Comment: I got it working! I appreciate the help lots!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you are failing to realise that you need to break the problem down into smaller steps. You (presumably) know how to read a single value from your file, and (presumably) know how to add a value to a vector. And you seem to realise that you need some kind of loop. What you have to do is put those techniques together to achieve the overall effect you want. Often when you do this you need to introduce *variables* to hold the intermediate values in your calculation. And that's the case here, we'll read the values from the file into variables and then we'll add the values in those variables to the vectors.

```
    vector<string> all_names;
    vector<int> all_scores;
    string name;
    int score;
    while (infile >> name >> score) // read one name and one score
    {
        all_names.push_back(name); // add that name to vector
        all_scores.push_back(score); // add that score to vector
    }
```

The advice you got in the comments, that if a problem is too complex you should work first on a simpler version is very good advice as well. Many beginners when given a large or complex task try and solve it all at once. Professionals don't work that way, neither should beginners.